# Problemas al levantar un nuevo proyecto en React teniendo otro ya levantado

Tags: reactjs

Quiero abrir un nuevo proyecto en React teniendo otro ya levantado y no me deja. Incluso cuando lo elimino e intento abrir uno nuevo me manda un error

```bash
$ npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\****\OneDrive\Documentos\React/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\****\OneDrive\Documentos\React\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\****\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-09T03_29_59_473Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Por defecto al levantar 1 aplicación de react está se ejecutara en el puerto 3000, si intentar levantar otra con el mismo puerto por defecto te notificara que ese puerto ya esta en uso. Debes colocar el mensaje que te aparece y que no te permite levantar ambas aplicaciones para descartar problemas con el puerto.

Comment: En la imagen del error que muestras hace referencia al que npm no encuentra el archivo package.json para mapear el script a utilizar que en tu caso es `start`.

Comment: De paso te invito a que visites el [tour] y veas como funciona SOes, también revisa la guía de [ask].